# Laravel - Using multiple `with()` eager load AND running a query on all

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I want to eager load several relationships (as below), which works as it should. However, I want to run a function on that eager load (as below). Normally I only do this on one eager load relationship, but I want to do it on all three. But the query is only working for the last eager load (i.e. `instagram_oauths`).

Is there a way to eager load multiple relationships ***AND*** run a separate query that applies to all 3 relationships? The below doesn't error out...only applies `return $oauth->withWeeklyStats($date);` to the last `with` variable, `instagram_oauths`.

```
return $data = Team::currentTeam()->with(['facebook_oauths', 'twitter_oauths', 'instagram_oauths' => function($oauth) use ($date) {
    return $oauth->withWeeklyStats($date);
}])->get();
```

Comment: I'm afraid is that NOT possible since larval make separate queries in order to fill relationships.

Comment: Agh. Was afraid so. Is there a clean (different) way of running this then? Running 3 `with` functions seems a it overkill to me.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: use query builder instead..

Comment: Take a look at this http://pastebin.com/Kf2ac8LD !

Comment: Why does 3 `with` functions seem overkill? Each one needs their own logic, makes complete sense to me. Otherwise, use `Query Scopes` and have the logic pre-built in the Model.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks, but getting error: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yeah, maybe scope is the way to go.

Comment: @MikeBarwick yes of course! my bad, I was in a hurry! please try this http://pastebin.com/ZbCWJ3yi

Comment: Sooo nice. Never seen that `array_fill_keys` method. Exactly what I was looking for. Write an answer...I'll accept ;)

Comment: Nevermind, I have. What you did makes sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT possible since larval make separate queries in order to fill relationships, instead, you can use this:

```
Team::currentTeam()->with(array_fill_keys(['facebook_oauths', 'twitter_oauths', 'instagram_oauths'], function($oauth) use($date) {
        return $oauth->withWeeklyStats($date);
}))->get();
```

Another alternative would be using `JOINS` with the `Query Builder`.

Comment: Weird though - I get the right output on first page load, but if I refresh again...data is gone...?

Comment: Nm...I had some weird caching I had to fix. :) Thanks for your help.